# Send an email (using flow) when the text field changes in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-formula, power-automate

I have a PowerApps App which is linked to a SharePoint List. When the user makes some changes to the text field in the app; I want the flow to send the user an email regarding the update.

I've been trying to track the SharePoint List entry and see if the entry is modified, then send an email. But so far I'm unable to do so.

I've been able to send an email when a text field changes to a specific text; but I'm looking for something where a particular entry in the list is changed.

```
When an item is created or modified > Condition (Column is equal to Yes) > Send email based on the condition
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Powerapps for the same, what I mean is you need Flow for this.

Create and Run your flow on SharePoint directly.
In your flow check whatever your field is changed, if changed then you can send the user email.

You do not need to depend on Powerapps, Flow can alone work for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you are using the Sharepoint `When an item is created or modified` Trigger in Power Automate (the tool formerly known as Flow)
2. Add a Trigger Condition for the column in question. Something along the lines of `@triggerBody()?.Status,'Pending')`

Trigger Conditions are not very well documented at the moment, but provide a powerful way to control when a Power Automate runs.